# Xamarin Forms save exceptions in a file

Tags: exception, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to be able to view and save in a file the exceptions thrown by my app when it crashes. Is there a tutorial on this topic? I've seen the Advanced App Lifecycle Demos and the crash handling there, but I don't really understand how to implement it in my app.

Comment: You are asking about a tutorial or off-site resource. I've marked this question for closing as it does not fit the StackOverflow QA style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the exception that caused an entire crash is not easy to archieve on your own. Luckily there's a way to get the exception using [Xamarin Insights](https://xamarin.com/insights). It's free to use for Xamarin customers.

You simply need to get an API key for your app on the website, add the NuGet package `Xamarin.Isights` and initialize it as described [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/insights/#quick-start) in your app.
Then you will receive crash reports everytime the user starts your app after a crash.

If you encounter startup crashes then you can use these lines of code to initialize Xamarin.Insights to receive reports for them:

```
Insights.HasPendingCrashReport += (sender, isStartupCrash) =>
{
  if (isStartupCrash) {
    Insights.PurgePendingCrashReports().Wait();
  }
};
Insights.Initialize("Your API Key");
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better off using [Xamarin Insights](https://insights.xamarin.com/docs), an application logging framework that will automatically log crashes and unhandled exceptions for you.

Answer (score 0):

In our team we didn't enjoyed the Xamarin Insights so we use such a construction:

```
    public async Task SafeCall(Func<Task> action)
    {
        var workedWrong = false;
        try
        {
            await action();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            workedWrong = true;
            // Here you copy all the data you need.
        }

        if (workedWrong)
        {
            // Here you show the notification that something went wrong and write all the relevant information to the file (you can find how to do it in official Xamarin manual).
        }
    }
```

Although it doesn't catch the iOS exceptions.